# Token Rewards Calculation and Distribution

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program, anchor-spl, rewards

I'm doing a script to calculate rewards for a handful of addresses (from sensors). The script runs weekly where it takes a bunch of addresses from our DB, cleans the data and calculates the associated weights per address to do a rewards distribution of tokens. I've done all this to this point.

I want to next, calculate the token rewards for that week. I don't have an annual emissions schedule yet nor for the week and wondering when I determine this weekly emissions amount whether I should do the calculation in an onchain program or inside the current script. What would be the best approach here?

Appreciate any help, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data on chain you can for example use a tool like clockwork.xyz to trigger the token distribution automatically every two weeks using a cron notation trigger.

They also have a token distribution program example:
https://github.com/clockwork-xyz/examples/tree/main/distributor/programs/distributor

Comment: thanks will look into it once I decide whether to do the calculation in a smart contract or inside my current script.